# (GNU inline assembly) How to use a register which not assigned from nor copy to the C variables?

Tags: c, gnu, inline-assembly

I'm writing inline assembly statements using a GNU-based toolchain, and there are three instructions within the inline assembly to update a single bit of a system register. The steps will be:

1. move(read) a system register to a general register
2. 'AND' it with the variable value from C code
3. move(write) back to the system register just read

in the instruction set I'm using, the inline assembly syntax is like this:

```
unsigned int OV_TMP = 0xffefffff;
asm volatile ( "mfsr %0, $PSW\n\t"
               "and %0, %0, %1\n\t"
               "mtsr %0, $PSW"
               :  : "r"(OV_TMP) : );
```

%1 is the register which I want to forward the value of OV_TMP into.

%0 is the problem for me, and my problem is :
**How to write the inline assembly code once there is a register used internally and is not assigned from nor copy to the C variables in the C code?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing to consider here is that, from the compiler's perspective, the register *is* assigned-to by the inline assembly, even if you don't use it again later.  That is, you're generating the equivalent of:

```
register unsigned int OV_TMP = 0xffefffff, scratch;

scratch = magic() & OV_TMP;
more_magic(scratch);
/* and then don't re-use scratch for anything from here on */
```

The magic and/or more_magic steps cannot be moved or combined away because of the `volatile`, so the compiler cannot simply delete the written-but-unused register.

The `mfsr` and `mtsr` look like powerpc instructions to me, and I would probably do the `and` step in C code (see footnote); but the following should generally work:

```
unsigned int OV_TMP = 0xffefffff, scratch;
asm volatile("mfsr %0, $PSW\n\t"
             "and %0, %0, %1\n\t"
             "mtsr %0, $PSW"
             : "=&r"(scratch) : "r"(OV_TMP));
```

Here the "=&r" constraint says that the output operand (`%0`) is written before the input operand (`%1`) is read.

---

Footnote: As far as I know (which is not very far, I've only ever done a tiny bit of ppc assembly) there's no need to keep the `mfsr` and `mtsr` instructions a specific distance apart, unlike certain lock-step sequences on other processors.  If so, I would write something more like this:

```
static inline unsigned int read_psw() {
    unsigned int result;
    asm volatile("mfsr %0, $PSW" : "=r"(result));
    return result;
}
static inline void write_psw(unsigned int value) {
    asm volatile("mtsr %0, $PSW" :: "r"(value));
}
#define PSW_FE0 0x00100000 /* this looks like it's FE0 anyway */
...
    write_psw(read_psw() & ~PSW_FE0); /* some appropriate comment here */
```